# What to do with operations for a specific kind of collection?

Tags: oop, scala, implicits

In several different places in my application, I need to take a `Seq[SalesRow]` and return a `Map[String,SalesRow]`, where the string is the name of a country.

I need to use this in several places. For example, I take a list of all SalesRows and get a global breakdown of sales by country. But in other places, I want to break down my sales by month and then by country (so `Map[Month,Seq[SalesRow]]` becomes `Map[Month,Map[String,Seq[SalesRow]]]`) - in still other places, I want to break down by day and then by country.

My question is: where do I put the (small) amount of logic that takes a `Seq[SalesRow]` and returns a map of countries to rows? Right now, I'm putting it in a companion object method, `SalesRow.byCountry(rows : Seq[SalesReport]`. Is that optimal?

A slightly crazier idea occurred to me, which is to create an implicit conversion from `Seq[SalesRow]` to `EnhancedSalesRowSeq`, which has a `byCountry` instance method. This appeals to me, because the operation is applicable to any sequence of SalesRows.

Is this a good idea?

Is adding the logic to the companion object my best choice, or are there better options?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are not aware the library comes with a [`groupBy`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/TraversableLike.html#groupBy%5BK%5D%28%28A%29%20%E2%87%92%20K%29%3aMap%5BK,%20Repr%5D) function. Basically given a `Seq[SalesRow]` it will give you a `Map[T, Seq[SalesRow]]` based on a function from `SalesRow` to `T`.

So if your function is easy you can easily get a map. I do like your idea of the enhanced seq in conjunction with putting the implicit in the `SalesRow` companion:

```
case class SalesRow(val month:Int, val country:String, 
  val person:String, val amount:Float)

class EnhancedRow(rows: Seq[SalesRow]) {
  def byCountry: Map[String, Seq[SalesRow]] = 
    rows.groupBy(_.country)
  def byMonth: Map[Int, Seq[SalesRow]] = 
    rows.groupBy(_.month)
  def byCountryByMonth: Map[String, Map[Int, Seq[SalesRow]]] = byCountry.mapValues(r => new EnhancedRow(rows).byMonth)
}

object SalesRow {
  implicit def toEnhanced(rows: Seq[SalesRow]) = new EnhancedRow(rows) 
}

object Test {
  def main(args:Array[String] = null) {
    val seq: Seq[SalesRow] = // ... fill this
    println(seq.byCountry)
    println(seq.byCountryByMonth)
    // same as:
    println(seq.byCountry.mapValues(_.byMonth))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If performance isn´t your main concern, you can put the logic at:

```
class RichTraversable[A](t: Traversable[A]) {
  def toMapBy[B](f: A => B): Map[B,A] = t.map{ e => (f(e),e) }.toMap
}
```

So if an implicit conversion you can turn every `Seq` into a `Map` with a member being the key.

Comment: Right, that's what I'm proposing in the second-to-last paragraph. My question is: is this a really weird or unexpected thing to do?

Comment: This is more or less equivalent to `groupBy` which is a library defined method.

Comment: It isn´t unexpected as you can infer from @huynhjl comment, that it is an oversight of me reimplmenting a library method.

Comment: Ok, my method implies uniqueness by key, so the values are one `B` element and not a `Seq[B]` compared to the library method

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you make encapsulating classes:

```
case class AllSalesTable(rows: Seq[SalesRow]) {
  def toSalesByCountry: SalesByCountry
}

case class ContrySalesTable(rows: Seq[SalesRow])

case class SalesByCountry(map: Map[String, CountrySalesTable])
```

Having someplace to put the method is one benefit, but another benefit is that you'll have greater type safety at the cost of a simple "`.rows`" here and there.

Comment: I agree with Daniel! My experience is that having classes or type defs even for simple data structures gives clearer code and the compiler often can help.